# Spark error using a variable in map operation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to iterate over a DataFrame and apply map operation over it's rows.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
case class SomeData(name:String, value: Int)

val input = Seq(SomeData("a",2), SomeData("b", 3)).toDF

val SOME_STRING = "some_string"

input.map(row =>
  SOME_STRING
).show
```

The above code fails with following exception,

```
ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 14, ip-xxxx, executor 4): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: L$iw;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2068)
```

However, if the variable is replaced with string, the code works.

```
input.map(row =>
  "some_string"
).show

+-----------+
|      value|
+-----------+
|some_string|
|some_string|
+-----------+
```

Is there anything wrong with the above code? Is it possible to use variables and function calls inside map operation.

Answer (score 1):

it's normal, your variable is define inside the driver then use inside a worker, so your worker dont know the variable.

what you can do is :

```
input.map(row =>
   val SOME_STRING = "some_string"
).show
```

you can also check broadcast variable : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

Comment: inside the driver I think you mean to say. And I think he means a parameter passed even though you are correct.